# PL/PGSQL Operator does not exist: information_schema.sql_identifier

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm writing a function to write a dynamic query.

This is the original query without function

```
SELECT b.column_name, a.default_flag, CAST(AVG(a.payment_ratio) AS NUMERIC), CAST(MAX(a.payment_ratio) AS NUMERIC)  FROM user_joined a, information_schema.columns b where b.column_name = 'payment_ratio' group by a.default_flag, b.column_name
```

Then, I put it into a function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test4(col text)
RETURNS TABLE(
    col_name TEXT,
    default_flag bigint,
    average NUMERIC,
    maximum NUMERIC) AS $$
BEGIN 
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT
('SELECT CAST(b.column_name AS TEXT), a.default_flag, CAST(AVG(a.'||col||') AS NUMERIC), CAST(MAX(a.'||col||') AS NUMERIC)  FROM user_joined a, information_schema.columns b where b.column_name = %I group by a.default_flag, b.column_name', col);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

When I try to run

```
SELECT * FROM test4('payment_ratio')
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: information_schema.sql_identifier = double precision
LINE 1: ... information_schema.columns b where b.column_name = payment_...
```

Is there anything wrong with my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns in `information_schema` have the (somewhat strange) data type `sql_identifier` and that can't be compared directly to a `text` value. You need to cast it in the SQL query.

You are also using the `%I` incorrectly. In the join condition the column name is a string constant so you need to use `%L` there. In the SELECT list, it's an identifier, so you need to use `%I` there.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test4(col text)
RETURNS TABLE(
    col_name TEXT,
    default_flag bigint,
    average NUMERIC,
    maximum NUMERIC) AS $$
BEGIN 
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
   FORMAT ('SELECT CAST(b.column_name AS TEXT), 
                   a.default_flag, CAST(AVG(a.%I) AS NUMERIC), 
                   CAST(MAX(a.'||col||') AS NUMERIC)  
            FROM user_joined a
              JOIN information_schema.columns b ON b.column_name::text = %L 
            group by a.default_flag, b.column_name', col, col);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Okay now that works! thanks, I didn't know that I should use %L